# How to move everything from Samsung Galaxy S20 to S23?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-smart-switch

I tried built-in feature (Smart Switch?) but it left most applications gray. How to copy everything? Are there any working solutions?

Comment: You should get the best result when old and new phone are connected directly via USB-C cable and then start migration. But a lot of app data is most likely bound to the device and thus can not be migrated.